# ModelState.IsValid false for empty string field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

My Model fields accepting numbers and empty string :

```
[DisplayName("Height")]
[RegularExpression (@"^\d*$", ErrorMessage="Height must be a number or left out   blank")]
public string Height { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Width")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Height must be a number or left out blank")]
public string Width { get; set; }
```

My view:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Width) %>:
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Width) %>

<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Height) %>:
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Height) %>
```

In controller action :

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Edit(MyModeltype model)
{
    model.Width = String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Width) ? "" : model.Width; //NEEDED?
    model.Height = String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Height) ? "" : model.Height; //NEEDED?

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        SaveSettings(model);

    return View("SomeView");
}
```

When I provide empty textboxes, Model.Width and .Height are passed as nulls and ModelState.IsValid is false. I just need to be able to pass the empty string. When omitting the regex attribute, same problem, so its not the regex. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `DisplayFormat` attribute to your model's properties:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
[DisplayName("Height")]
[RegularExpression (@"^\d*$", ErrorMessage="Height must be a number or left out   blank")]
public string Height { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
[DisplayName("Width")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*$", ErrorMessage = "Height must be a number or left out blank")]
public string Width { get; set; }
```

This will ensure empty textbox values are not converted to NULL.

Alternatively, you could explicitly define your getters and setters to convert nulls to empty strings:

```
private string _width;
public string Width
{
    get { return _width ?? string.Empty; }
    set { _width = value ?? string.Empty; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you displaying the error message in your View.  So that might be causing the problem, though I'm not sure.  Anyway try this and see if it works:

```
<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Width) %>:
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Width) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Width) %>

<%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Height) %>:
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Height) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Height) %>
```

Comment: this didn't help. Was this for debugging purposes ?

Comment: No it's the built in way for the framework to display error messages if your regular expression on the model property fails.  You probably should include if you want client side validation to work properly.  Also having empty strings on fields that are not marked as required should work.  Are there any other properties on your model that is not set properly by your View?  That would cause the model state to be invalid.